# FastAPI in docker - module not found error from main

Tags: python, docker, fastapi

I have a (locally) working fastAPI-app. Now I intend to bring it to docker. I followed the instruction as [in the docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/docker/). When starting up the container it stops. The log tells

```
  File "/code/./app/main.py", line 12, in <module>
    from database import get_session
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'database'
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
# 
FROM python:3.10
WORKDIR /code
COPY ./requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /code/requirements.txt
COPY ./app /code/app
CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--proxy-headers", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]
```

If I check the existence of the files with `sudo docker run -it fastapi bash` I see all files in place:

```
root@d6d938b2a0da:/code/app# ls -la
total 40
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Mar 17 12:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  4096 Mar 17 12:31 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root     0 Mar 16 19:58 __init__.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root   744 Mar 16 19:58 database.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 12288 Mar 17 12:26 db.sqlite3
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  1170 Mar 16 19:58 main.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root   602 Mar 16 19:58 models.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  2942 Mar 16 19:58 populate.py
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root  4096 Mar 16 19:58 templates
```

Why can't main.py load from database.py in the docker?

The dot in "/code/./app/main.py" looks suspicious. But main.py starts...

Comment: Please also post your docker file. My guess is that your CWD is not in `/code/app` so it cannot find `database.py`. Also `__init__.py` makes `/code/app` into a module, so imports could be relative `from .database import get_session` or `from app.database import get_session`. **Edit:** probably works locally if your IDE marks `app` as source root or something similar.

Comment: I agree. But exactly this is done in the FastAPI documentation

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a Docker problem. You have some confusion about how Python imports work.

Your cwd is `/code`, and your files are installed in `/code/app`. From the perspective of Python, all of your modules exist in the `app` package. This is why your `uvicorn` command line refers to module `app.main`.

You would need to modify your code to either use absolute imports:

```
from app.database import get_session
```

Or relative imports:

```
from .database import get_session
```